# Не инсталлировать Psycopg2 в django

Tags: django, macos, psycopg2

Столкнулся с проблемой при инсталляции Psycopg2, решения которой не смог найти.

Я действовал согласно руководству на официальном сайте: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html

- Установил HomeBrew
- C его помощью установил PostgreSQL и PostgreSQL client library.

Всё прошло успешно.

Единственное, я не смог отыскать файл pg_config:
Команда

```
which -a pg_config
```

дала адрес 
`/usr/local/bin/pg_config`,
но ни одна папка bin не содержала pg_config.

Далее, при попытке установить Psycopg2 командой 
`pip install psycopg2` или
`pip3 install psycopg2`,

выдаётся следующая ошибка, природу которой я понять не могу:

```
 gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-
3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/green.o build/temp.macosx-
10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/utils.o 
build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-
3.8/psycopg/libpq_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/win32_support.o 
build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/solaris_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-
3.8/psycopg/aix_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-
3.8/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/cursor_type.o 
build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/column_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-
3.8/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-
3.8/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-
3.8/psycopg/replication_message_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-
3.8/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/conninfo_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-
3.8/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-
3.8/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_list.o 
build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-
3.8/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-
3.8/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/microprotocols.o 
build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-
3.8/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-
3.8/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/kirill/PycharmProjects/VKOauth/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='/private/var/folders/6t/p9x1jmgd65g_7bn0nzk_lm6m0000gn/T/pip-install-gf_nx13o/psycopg2/setup.py';
f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', 
'\n');f.close();
exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
/private/var/folders/6t/p9x1jmgd65g_7bn0nzk_lm6m0000gn/T/pip-record-zd6qdg7e/install-record.txt
 --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 
/Users/kirill/PycharmProjects/VKOauth/venv/include/site/python3.8/psycopg2" 
failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/6t/p9x1jmgd65g_7bn0nzk_lm6m0000gn/T/pip-
install-gf_nx13o/psycopg2/
```

Был бы чрезвычайно признателен если бы кто-нибудь смог прояснить этот момент.
Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Установите gcc или переустановите его

Comment: Спасибо! Я сделал это, но проблема осталась в том же виде, к сожалению(

Comment: OS какая? (ещё 5 симв)

Comment: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: возможно дело в этом `ld: library not found for -lssl`

Comment: Сделал ```pip install ld```, но результат такой же и сообщение тоже. Спасибо!

Comment: Не пробовали поставить psycopg2-binary?

Comment: Пробовал, он ставится, но для библиотеки, которую я хочу поставить (django_heroku), он не подходит.